# Can I re-assemble my RAID 5 on only 2 drives using mdadm to recover my data?

Tags: centos, data-recovery, mdadm, nas

I have a 3 drives RAID 5 on a CentOS NAS but 1 drive died. Since then, CentOS boot in emergency mode and I can't manage to get access to my data.

I tried `mdadm --assemble --scan` and command returns `mdadm: /dev/md2 assembled from 1 drive - not enough to start the array` while I have 2 disks running.

Is it possible to rebuild RAID 5 on the 2 remaining disks using mdadm ?

Comment: You can't rebuild a RAID 5 array with two disks. RAID 5 requires at least three disks. You'll need to add a third and then rebuild.

Comment: There is no way to access data using only 2 disks ?

Comment: No, there is no way. But if you had [unRAID](https://unraid.net), then the dead disk would be transparently simulated for you, while you are waiting for Amazon to ship you the new replacement disk. ;-)

Comment: @Pourko lol ok, I was hoping to have the opportunity to make the data transfer to my new NAS without having to buy a new disk ...

Comment: A three disk RAID5 can run with two disks

Comment: The array will run with two disks but to completely rebuild it with the parity in place, you need three.

Comment: For a three disk RAID5, any two disks can be used to recreate the third, regardless of which disk holds which parity stripe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have an out-of-date RAID superblock. Did one disk fail (removed from the array) and then another one died?

Does `mdadm --assemble --force -v ...` work?

You should be able to rebuild the superblock with for example `mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 --assume-clean /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 missing`

But you may have inconsistent data in case of a double failure, and possibly another disk failing. If you get the array back, mount read-only and try to recover most important data first.

Check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621824/re-assemble-out-of-date-raid5) answer.

Comment: Why I didn't think to use verbose mode ...? anyway, mdadm says `/dev/sda1-c1-d1 is identified as a member of /dev/md2` and also sdc1 & sdd1 `(possibly out of date)` so I'll try `--force`

Comment: I have this since 15 min : https://i.imgur.com/KFPTje9.png How long can it take ?

Comment: In the picture you linked, it appears the `mdadm` command has already completed successfully and returned to prompt, but then the `systemd-fsck` running in the background has written two messages onto the console session. Whenever something like that happens, the shell is not aware of it and cannot redisplay the prompt automatically: just press Enter again to get a new prompt. The second of the two `systemd-fsck` messages looks like the filesystem check has been successfully passed.

Comment: Finally, I was able to recover all my data using `mdadm --assemble --force -v /dev/mdX /dev/sdx1 ...` then mount & rsync. Thanks to `mdadm --force` I managed to launch RAID 5 on only 2 disks while one was faulty. Then I had to segment the data recovery because the RAID was dropping each time rsync was trying to copy one particular file. I identified this corrupted file and excluded it from sync. Thx a lot for all your responses, this incident gave me more xp with mdadm & RAIDs.